# Method in class cannot be applied to given types. Required: no arguments

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm new to coding so this will probably be a very simple question.

When I compile I get the error:

```
GradeAnalyzer.java:49: error: method getAverage in class GradeAnalyzer cannot be applied to given types;
      myAnalyzer.getAverage(myClassroom);
                ^
  required: no arguments
  found: ArrayList<Integer>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Which for the life of me I can't understand why. I thought my problem was it needed an argument but I've got one, being 'myClassroom'.

Here is my bulk code: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Faraday_/pexqKb

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. You may need to edit your question based on these guidelines. In particular, do not post external links for your code, instead put those down here.

Comment: It looks like your `getAverage()` function does not expect any argument but you are passing `myClassroom` as argument. Until we see your code we cannot comment further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getAverage()` method doesn't need any arguments. But you have passed a one when you calling it. That's the error you get in here. If you want to pass an argument, you need to change your `getAverage()` method signature like this,

```
public int getAverage(ArrayList<Integer> grades )
```

Instead of creating a list inside your method then you can use this grades parameter you passed inside the method.

Answer (score 2):

Your method getAverage() should accept an ArrayList as an argument, in order to remove compilation error. 
Try this

```
public int getAverage(ArrayList<Integer> myClassroom ) {

    if (myClassroom .size() < 1) {
      System.out.println("Error. Not items in Arraylist.");
      return 0;
    }

    else {
      int sum = 0;

      for (int grade : myClassroom) {
        sum += grade;
      }

      int average = sum / myClassroom .size();

      System.out.println(average);

      return average;

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a getter method

```
  myAnalyzer.getAverage(myClassroom);
```

As most auto generated getter methods, it doean't receive any arguments, so it doesn't expect and can't receive parameter as `myClassroom`, change your code accordingly

```
 myAnalyzer.getAverage();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing argument to getAverage() in main method. But getAverage() has no parameters in it. So, You just need to change the getAverage() method. Here is the code for getAverage().

```
public int getAverage(ArrayList<Integer> grades) {


    if (grades.size() < 1) {
      System.out.println("Error. Not items in Arraylist.");
      return 0;
    }

    else {
      int sum = 0;

      for (int grade : grades) {
        sum += grade;
      }

      int average = sum / grades.size();

      System.out.println(average);

      return average;

    }

  }
```